# no device file /dev/mem on virtual machine, how to create one

Tags: linux, driver, device

Rent a VPS (Ubuntu 12.04), have root access, however, don't see the device file /dev/mem.
Is there a way to create it to access bios info. Thanks.

Comment: Better asked on http://serverfault.com

Comment: How can a VPS have a BIOS? It is not running on the hardware, but inside an hypervisor.... So there is no BIOS info available to you...

Comment: I installed VMPlayer and run Ubuntu in it, it does see "BIOS" info (probably from hypervisor).

Answer (score 1):

```
mknod /dev/mem c `sed -n 's/ mem$//p' /proc/devices` 1
```